# Angular Init ConfigArrays from Database

Tags: angular, database

im trying to make a singlecall,
from the Database to Init an Array of Configmeasures (ID, Titel).

My Problem is the IDtoStringpipe is called before the service has been inititialized.

Maybe you can give me a hint.

Best regards,

Stefan

Comment: please be more specific and show some code

Answer (score 0):

At the very first this is the Service.
It should make a Call to the Database, store the Data and after that i would work with the array

```js
 export class SCBuchungsartenService {

        Buchungsarten: Ibuchungsart[] = [];

        constructor(  private http: HttpClient){
        }



        async init(){
                 const data = await this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/config/Buchungsarten')
                 .toPromise();
               this.Buchungsarten = data;
       }



        public getBuchungsarten(){
            return this.Buchungsarten;
        }

        public getBuchungsartAZ(): Ibuchungsart[]{
            return this.Buchungsarten.filter(a => a.AUSWAHL == true)
        }

        public getBuchungsartenName(id: number): string { 
            return this.Buchungsarten.filter(a => a.ID == id)[0]?.Bezeichnung!
        }
    }
```

After that the pipe should use the function getBuchungsartenName(id).

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'BaToString'
})
export class BuchungsartStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public buchungsarten?: Ibuchungsart[];
  constructor(private BuchungsartService: SCBuchungsartenService){

  }


  transform(value: number| undefined): String {
    
    var returnValue: String = "Unbekannt";
    if(value !== undefined){ 
      let name =  this.BuchungsartService.getBuchungsartenName(value); 
      if (name!==undefined && name.length > 0) {
          return name
      }

    }

    return returnValue; 
  }

}
```

But the Array is Empty when the Pipe start on Init.